# CSS: Parent/Child height issue

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I'm struggling with a sidebar height.

My container is now showing the correct height (that of the content inside), but my sidebar that should be using 100% of that height is still not appearing.

I've implemented one of the suggestions below (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) but the sidebar's still not appearing.

I'm sure this is a simple one for you pros, any tips appreciated!

Thanks,

Tom

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/tomperkins/wy52B/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this way](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) of clearing floats, it's a lot cleaner and easier to use.

Comment: Thanks, a neat solution. Still not making the sidebar appear though. Any ideas?

Comment: having a hard time parsing through all the code in jsfiddle, maybe if you could do a simple example with main content and sidebar, omit any other unnecessary tags and it's easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

## Don't use clearfix

It's not necessary in most situations, and it's *definitely* not semantic.

The simple solution for most cases: float the parent.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent
{
  float: left;
  width: 100%; /*or whatever you want it to be*/
}

.child
{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have the parent centered, so can't float.

Comment: Do you have more children than the floated children? because you could just add `clear:both` to the next child's styles.